# simple Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

i have a list with a string of tr (html table row), each tr has 3 td.

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to filter out the data from a web page.

```
var data= from tr in content.ChildNodes.Where(c =>c.Name.Equals("tr"))                    
         select tr;

<tr><td></td><td>aaa</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>bbb</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>aaa</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>aaa</td><td></td></tr>
```

....

I want to get all values grouped by td[2], ie: aaa, bbb

Thanks.

Updated:  data.GroupBy(tr => tr.ChildNodes.Where(e => e.Name == "td")
                     .Skip(1).First().InnerText); works fine

Thanks all.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data.GroupBy(tr => tr.ChildNodes
                     .Where(e => e.Name == "td")
                     .Skip(1).First().Value));
```

Of course, this assumes there will be at least 2 `td`s in each `tr`.  If not, then you must also do some null checking in the `Skip(1).First()` call.

Comment: thanks. that's exactly i'm looking for. Sometimes, i cannot think of a simple way like this. silly me.

Comment: No problem.  I'd encourage you to try LINQPad so that you can practice and experiment: http://www.linqpad.net/.  Also, if you used this answer, you should accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This should save the TD values into a collection.

```
var entries = from td in data.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td").Where(node => node.InnerHtml != string.Empty) select td.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: i'll play with htmlagilitypack a bit more. Thanks.